# Naming Conventions for Class Methods and Attributes

Tags: python, class, methods, attr

What would be a best practice to name the class attributes and its methods (functions).

```
class Base():   
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'My Name'
    def print_this(self):
        print "Hello"
```

Create an instance of the class:

```
a = Base()
```

Get an idea what methods and attributes available in this class:

```
print dir(a)
```

Getting this output:

```
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'name', 'print_this']
```

From reading the names in **dir()** output it is impossible to see where the variables are (class attributes) and where the methods (class functions).

What naming conventions to use to differentiate the variables from functions (or attrs from methods)?

Comment: If I were you, I'd go read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for naming conventions

Comment: Also have a look at flake8 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8 And start using it.

Comment: Looking at PEP 8 is a great idea for sure, but it's also worth noting that trying to implement a naming convention like this in Python is full of pitfalls.  For instance, should a `property` get the attribute variable styling or the instance method styling?  Depending on context, they are equally valid.

Comment: `print {name: type(a[name]) for name in dir(a)}` - there, now you know the types

Comment: There is no correct answer to this question. "What naming conventions should I use?" <-- opinion-based. "How can I determine what is a method and what is a variable, just by its name?" <-- you can't.

Comment: @SilasRay We already have this situation: functions are lowercase, classes are CamelCase. And both are callable, and - in a certain way - interchangeable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methods should generally have a verb in them, eg `print_this`, `calculate_that`, `save`, because they perform some action.

Attributes and properties will just be a bare noun, eg `name`, `status`, `count` as they just contain a value or, in the case of a property, the underlying function should calculate and return a value, without other side-effects.

Your question is vague though:

- is it about naming conventions in Python? For this you should refer to the [famous PEP8 document](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- is it about how to distinguish between methods and attributes by looking at their names? for this see my rule of thumb above
- is it about how to distinguish between methods and attributes programmatically? In this case you can use the `inspect` module to provide a definitive answer, for example:

  ```
  import inspect

  for attr in dir(a):
      if inspect.ismethod(getattr(a, attr)):
          print '%s is a method' % attr
      else:
          print '%s is an attribute or property' % attr
  ```

Comment: Booleans are somewhat harder to name. `x.printable` is ok, but `y.calculate_slowly` is ambiguously a method, based on name alone

Comment: The `callable()` trick doesn't work always. What if an attribute or property contains a callable?

Comment: @glglgl good point... have changed it to use `inspect.ismethod`

Comment: @Eric - for booleans, prefix the variable with 'is' or 'do'.   For example, 'is_printable' and 'do_calculate_slowly'.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson: `is_` I agree with, but as an imperative verb, `do_` strongly implies "method" to me